# CONFUSION IN sentences formation

Tags: adverbs, comparative-constructions

> I could have done as good as you did
>   or
>   I could have done as good as you.

Which sentence is correct and why? And can we use "as better as"—I mean is there any phrase like that?

And is this sentence correct?

> What will you do after my going/his going??

Comment: Although StoneyB divided his answer into ***three*** sections, you've actually only asked ***two*** questions (his first two points both address your first question). For future reference though, please note that you should only ask ***one*** question at a time, or it might simply get closed.

Comment: @roopa: I think you should delete your second question and open a new one.

Answer (score 6):

1. Neither of your first two sentences is correct—you must use the adverb *well* instead of the adjective *good*. With that correction, both sentences are grammatical, and neither is to be preferred.

   > I could have done as **well** as you did.
   >   or
   >   I could have done as **well** as you.
2. *Better* is the comparative grade for both *good* and *well*, so that part is OK; but the construction ***as*** ADJECTIVE **as** must be replaced with *ADJECTIVE **than*** when *ADJECTIVE* is in the comparative degree:

   > I could have done **better than** you.
   >   She is much **smarter than** he is.
3. “What will you do after his going?” doesn’t violate any rules, but it is very unlikely to be spoken or written. Ordinarily we would say “What will you do after **he goes**?”.